# Owned types collection is never updated in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, owned-types

I have an aggregate defined like this:

```
public class Product {
    public int LocalId { get; private set; }
    public Something Something { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Price> Prices { get; private set; }
}

public class Something {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Price {
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

And a schema defined like this:

```
private void DefineProduct(ModelBuilder builder) =>
    builder
        .Entity<Product>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasKey(p => p.LocalId);
            builder
                .OwnsOne(p => p.Something, smth =>
                {
                    smth.ToTable("somethings");
                })
                .OwnsMany(p => p.Prices, pp =>
                {
                    pp.ToTable("prices");
                });
        });
```

When a price change is requested, I do this (inside the product method not included here for brevity):

```
Prices.First(p => p.Type == type).Value = newValue;
```

And then I try to save the product like this:

```
public async Task UpdateProperties(Product product, IEnumerable<object> props)
{
    _context.Attach(product);
    _context.Update(product);

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        _context.Update(prop);
    }

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Who the hell allowed such a bug to go into a production release?");
    }
}
```

Now I should mention that the product comes in from an initial query whose results were not tracked (via `AsNoTracking()` call), that's why I'm calling the `Attach` method in the first line of the method body. The problem is that I'm hitting that `catch` statement with an exception message saying:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
>   row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
>   loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for
>   information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency
>   exceptions."}

The thing is that I'm not updating the same product anywhere else and that's the only place touching it. Also I use `AsNoTracking` as the default. If I comment out the line with `_context.Update(prop);`, then there's no exception raised, but the price is not being updated. Also, if I don't update that prices collection but the `Something` property, everything goes well. What. The. Hell.

Comment: Hi, not entirely sure: `_context.Attach(product).State = EntityState.Modified;` to signal EF that it should re-track it. (For EF not-core: `_context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;`)

Comment: I'm getting the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core documentation for [Collections of owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) explicitly states that you have to define the owned entity PK (as opposed to `OwnsOne` where the shadow FK is normally used as PK).

Hence you need to either define its own PK (like `Id` you did), or composite PK - for instance, if `Price.Type` is unique inside the owner, then you can use something like

```
pp.HasKey("LocalId", "Type");
```

and avoid the additional `Id` column.

Comment: The thing is that the primary key has been created by the EF framework in the database. It kind of opposes that sentence from the link you provided saying that owned types need a primary key. Since it got created automatically, why do I need to mention it explicitly in my schema definition? It should either all be explicit with exceptions shouting at me that I shall not define an owned collection type without explicitly naming the primary key, or 100% implicit, so the auto created pk should be enough. Now it’s just confusing...

Comment: Also getting an exception of type DbUpdateConcurrencyException doesn’t help debugging the problem :(

Comment: You wrote "My code started behaving properly when I added an Id field on the Price object". So it wasn't created automatically for you before that. Anyway, the link is the official EF Core documentation, so in case it's up-to-date, then it should be what it says. Btw, you haven't specified EF Core version, which also might be important since they change/break many things between even minor versions. What about exception, they use basically for every possible error - for instance trying to delete or update non existing record. So yeah, the message is misleading :-(

Comment: Ok, then I missed an important bit of an information - the db table had a primary key column called id that was created by the orm. Anyway, thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer for the future lost travelers out there, although I would gladly hear an explanation from someone who knows more than me about EF Core. I also think I understand the reason for that behavior, but I'm not sure. My code started behaving properly when I added an Id field on the `Price` object. My suspicion is that without an explicitly visible id property, no amount of attaching or updating would make EF see and that object. I would welcome a documentation section about it though...

Comment: while i couldn't quickly find documentation that says what happens when you don't provide a Key, here is documentation about [Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys). by convention you added a Key when you added Price.Id.